# In operator not working when the variable is inputted and works when the value is assigned

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

So I have a yaml file. I'm trying to pull values from it. Currently I dont loop it and get the values i want, wil do that when this is solved. But it cannot find the key when I input the variable I want to use. it works otherwise.

```
import yaml
f = open(path)
blueprints = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
id = 682

if (id in blueprints) == True:
    act = input("\ncopying\ninvention\nproducts\nskills\nmanufacturing\nActivity: ")
    if (act in blueprints[id]["activities"] == True):
        print(blueprints[id]["activities"][act])
    else:
        print("could not find the activity")
else:
    print("could not find id")
```

So the output is "could not find the activity" which means the first in operator works but the second does not. I tried doing the exact opposite by inputting the first variable "id" instead of "act" but it did not work too. And yes I did turn the "id" variable into integer. The yaml file is too big but here is a part of it:

```
681:
    activities:
        copying:
            time: 480
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 86
                typeID: 38
            products:
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 165
            time: 600
        research_material:
            time: 210
        research_time:
            time: 210
    blueprintTypeID: 681
    maxProductionLimit: 300
682:
    activities:
        copying:
            time: 480
        manufacturing:
            materials:
            -   quantity: 133
                typeID: 38
            products:
            -   quantity: 1
                typeID: 166
            time: 600
        research_material:
            time: 210
        research_time:
            time: 210
    blueprintTypeID: 682
    maxProductionLimit: 300
```

I'm still very new to python and I don't have anyone to ask as I'm learning myself. I am sorry if the solution is easy.

Comment: Provided your input is actually correct, just do `act in blueprints[id]["activities"]`, remove the `== True`.  Your `input` must be an exact match of any key in `activities`.  The `in` operator already returns a boolean value.

Comment: Total aside, but stuff like this, `if (id in blueprints) == True` is redundant. `if (whatever) == True:` should always just be `if whatever:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes required, see comments.  [Sample here](https://repl.it/repls/WellwornCuteWorkplace):

```
import yaml
# f = open(path)
with open('data.yaml', 'r') as f:   # change to use with context manager which will handle file closing
                                    # Just change 'data.yaml', remember to indent the block.
  blueprints = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
  id_no = 682                       # change to use id_no
                                    # id is a built in function you don't want to overwrite.

  if id_no in blueprints:           # Remove the superfluous == True
      act = input("\ncopying\ninvention\nproducts\nskills\nmanufacturing\nActivity: ")
      if act in blueprints[id_no]["activities"]:  # Remove the erroneous == True, which causes your result to fail
          print(blueprints[id_no]["activities"][act])
      else:
          print("could not find the activity")
  else:
      print("could not find id")
```

Test run:

```
copying
invention
products
skills
manufacturing
Activity: copying
{'time': 480}
```

Note: Remember your `input` (`act`) must be an exact match of your keys in `activities`, case sensitive as well.  Otherwise you'll want to convert the cases to compare.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know id was a built in function and did not know in was supposed to use that way. this works, thanks